# electron-builder node-gyp is throwing 'building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64' error

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, clang, electron-builder

###### Tl;dr

> How do I cross compile an electron.js app, which contains native-addon, for both Apple and Intel chips?

###### In details

I have a Macbook M1 machine which has macos 12.x installed. When I am trying to cross compile an electron.js app using `electron-builder` the native-addons which are used in the app are throwing this error.

The `arm64` version of the app compiles just fine but the `x64` keeps throwing the error.

```
    ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
    ld: in '/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib', building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have set the `electron-builder` target as:

```
"target": {
        "target": "default",
        "arch": [
          "arm64",
          "x64"
        ]
      }
```

```
$ yarn build && cross-env electron-builder build --mac --publish never
```

Full source code of the project is available here: [OpenMTP](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/openmtp/blob/feature/m1/package.json#L18)

I am attaching the truncated build log here:

```
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=ffi-napi version=4.0.3
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=node-mac-permissions version=2.2.0
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=usb-detection version=4.13.0
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=ref-napi version=3.0.3
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 1

node-gyp-build
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
      LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/prep_cif.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/types.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/raw_api.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/java_raw_api.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/closures.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/x86/ffiw64.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/x86/unix64.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/ffi/deps/libffi/src/x86/win64.o
      LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/libffi.a
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ffi_bindings/src/ffi.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ffi_bindings/src/callback_info.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ffi_bindings/src/threaded_callback_invokation.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/ffi_bindings.node
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
    
                    errorOut=gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
    gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
    gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.10 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
    gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
    gyp info spawn args [
    gyp info spawn args   '/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
    gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    gyp info spawn args   'make',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/path/to/project/node_modules/ffi-napi/build/config.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/Users/home/.electron-gyp/17.0.0/include/node/common.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/home/.electron-gyp/17.0.0',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/home/.electron-gyp/17.0.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/path/to/project/node_modules/ffi-napi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
    gyp info spawn args ]
    gyp info spawn make
    gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    warning: nothing.o has no symbols
    ../deps/libffi/src/java_raw_api.c:328:46: warning: 'ffi_java_raw_size' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      ffi_java_raw *raw = (ffi_java_raw*)alloca (ffi_java_raw_size (cif));
                                                 ^
    ../deps/libffi/config/mac/x64/ffi.h:299:56: note: 'ffi_java_raw_size' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    size_t ffi_java_raw_size (ffi_cif *cif) __attribute__((deprecated));
                                                           ^
    ../deps/libffi/src/java_raw_api.c:331:3: warning: 'ffi_java_ptrarray_to_raw' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      ffi_java_ptrarray_to_raw (cif, avalue, raw);
      ^
    ../deps/libffi/config/mac/x64/ffi.h:295:93: note: 'ffi_java_ptrarray_to_raw' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    void ffi_java_ptrarray_to_raw (ffi_cif *cif, void **args, ffi_java_raw *raw) __attribute__((deprecated));
                                                                                                ^
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from ../deps/libffi/src/closures.c:524:
    ../deps/libffi/src/dlmalloc.c:2937:33: warning: arithmetic on a null pointer treated as a cast from integer to pointer is a GNU extension [-Wnull-pointer-arithmetic]
          used = fp - (m->topsize + TOP_FOOT_SIZE);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ../deps/libffi/src/dlmalloc.c:2193:17: note: expanded from macro 'TOP_FOOT_SIZE'
      (align_offset(chunk2mem(0))+pad_request(sizeof(struct malloc_segment))+MIN_CHUNK_SIZE)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ../deps/libffi/src/dlmalloc.c:1693:55: note: expanded from macro 'chunk2mem'
    #define chunk2mem(p)        ((void*)((char*)(p)       + TWO_SIZE_T_SIZES))

    ........
    truncated
    ........
                            ~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
    29 warnings generated.
    ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
    ld: in '/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib', building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make: *** [Release/ffi_bindings.node] Error 1
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
    gyp ERR! command "/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node" "/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /path/to/project/node_modules/ffi-napi
    gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
    gyp ERR! not ok 
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by adding `npmRebuild: false` to the `build` object in the package.json file.

```
  "build": { 
   .....
   "npmRebuild": false,
}
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/6630#issuecomment-1046047751)